# tmux で画面分割・クラスタノードへの ssh を自動化できるか

Tags: tmux

最近 tmux をさわりはじめました。よくやる作業として、

- pane を N 個に分割する
- それぞれでクラスタのノードそれぞれに ssh する

をやるのですが、これを自動化して、コマンド一つで

- N 個の pane で ssh が完了している状態

にできないでしょうか。

今現在では、N-1 回 pane 分割を行ったのちに、それぞれで (IP を変えながら) ssh していて、いまいち非効率的だなと感じているので質問しています。

Comment: tmux scriptingで検索すると[色々出てきます](http://blog.htbaa.com/news/tmux-scripting)。sshでパスワード認証を使っているならagentを使うとか一工夫必要かもしれません。

Comment: tmuxinatorというツールがあります: https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tmuxifier](https://github.com/jimeh/tmuxifier) の方が、今自分のやりたいことに近そうです。

- 今のセッションに対して、あらかじめ定義した window layout をくっつける

が実現できそうです。

Answer (score 1):

@todashuta さんに、紹介いただいた、 [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) が自分の欲しいものに近そうです。

これは何かというと session を yaml で宣言的に定義できるツールっぽいです。